# How can I delete a blank column from a form responses sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Even though the column has no data, I cannot delete it and instead get the below message:

```
There was a problem
Cannot delete column with form data. Consider hiding the column instead.
```

[image: Error window when deleting a blank column]

I want to delete Column N

[Make a copy of my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yq-i3upGLaAnY_DdBZHQP3GnK42gUNijkqsWKyXJKxk/copy)

The form does not seem to have a no-named question field or something, I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your form...I think that's the problem

[image]

Comment: Clearing the form didn't work for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: the formula `=N1=""` gives FALSE, there is a 0 in that cell

Comment: That formula returns TRUE to me